# Is there any way to stop wildfires?

Tags: dont-starve

Given that [this happened](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117557/how-long-do-burnt-trees-stay-around), I'm wondering if there's anything you can do to stop a wildfire that's gone out of control. As far as I've played (which admittedly isn't very far), I've never found a way to carry around water or anything.

Is there any way that I can stop a wildfire that's tearing through my forest biome or do I simply have to wait for it to run out of things to burn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly no, there's no way to stop any kind of fire, you're just supposed to let it die on its own.

You can act preventively, setting up your crops and your eventual reserve of wood with enough space to reduce the damages, but in the end, in case of fire, you can just sit back and collect charcoal and ashes afterwards.

Even rain, that by logic should help controlling the fire, actually [makes the fire consume the objects more quickly](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Rain#Negative_Effects).

Comment: Well, rain makes a firepit consume it's fuel more quickly, which causes it to go out sooner.  You could say instead of it burning the fuel twice as fast, that it only burns half as long.

Comment: @Kexlox the end result is the same though, it burns faster but not fast enough to prevent the fire from spreading to the other trees. You still get charred remains of everything around you, you anly get them quickier!

Comment: I think the problem is with the paradigm that is used to model fire. When it rains on a fire in real life, it causes the fire to go out, but does not cause it to use up the fuel (at least not wood; gas would continue to seep without providing a flame). Perhaps it will be updated and change to be more realistic in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to stop wildfires?

It really depends on the layout of the forest and ignition point. In most cases, once a tree in a densely lit forest goes up, the rest will as well; your only option is to run for your life.

That said, if the fire starts out at the edges, in an area that is less dense, then it *may* be possible to run in and chop a tree or two down to create a firebreak, but timing is critical.

For example, I had a dense forest with some spider nests around. I wanted to set up a campfire so that I could hang around for a few days while carefully clearing out the nests, but there was nowhere safe to start a fire without igniting the whole forest. I went to the corner against the shore and chopped a couple of trees to make a gap and was able to make a campfire. I also backed up my save-game so that I could do some experiments like burning the spider nests without burning down the forest which I did successfully by burning a tree next to the nest after chopping down a few trees between those and the rest of the forest. Finally, during one experiment, it rained and lighting struck and started a fire near the edge. I was able to run ahead and chop down a tree to stop the spread. Of course this was possible due to a confluence of fortunate circumstances including:

- I already had an ax with low-wear equipped which saved valuable time
- The fire started at the edge, in a sort of “tail” or “galaxy arm” which was kind of like a fuse, so “cutting” it was effective
- (Somehow) I happened to have the presence of mind to compensate for the time it takes to chop down a tree and managed to run *sufficiently ahead* of the fire to be able to cut it down before the fire reached it

So yes, a forest fire *can* be stopped, but only under the right—and rare—circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Digging up smaller plants that are on fire can reduce the spread of fires, also giving unburnt drops. If caught early enough, a fire can be put out on smoldering objects with smoke coming off of them with damage to the player. Using this tactic is effective when there is something valuable in the area, like pig houses or chests. Leaving an area that is on fire has proven effective for me in the past when I was trying to burn down several spider nests I went through a wormhole to avoid being burnt, however upon return, the fires had all gone out before getting past a few trees in a dense forest where they should have spread without abandon normally. I assume this is because the area was no longer loading after I went through the wormhole, but this was in normal don't starve, not together. Not sure if it even works in dst. There are watering cans and ice staffs and the like in dst, maybe somehow they can be used, along with fertilizing dried out brambles to avoid unnecessary fires